# React native app is crashing when a notification opened when the app is killed or quit state

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-notifications

[I am using firebase for push notification and this is the method triggered when I open the notification from quit or killed state messaging().getInitialNotification(). Some how it works in Android 9, 10 version but from 11 onwards its not working and app is crashing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBp4i.jpg)